# Is it problematic to use a user ID as an array index when looping in VueJS where multiple points of user input are associated by that ID?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

A couple of times, I've designed systems where I need multiple inputs generated in a loop, which will take data stored against that entity's records. Hence, I use the entity's ID as an array key for the referencing.

In example:

```html
<table>
    ...
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="member in employees">
            <td>@{{ member.name }}</td>
            <td>@{{ member.email }}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" v-model="emp_codes[member.id]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" v-model="emp_cats[member.id]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This creates arrays with user ID indexes (`[member.id]`). This works, but I could see issues arising from this over time & database growth (large IDs as array index causing memory issues in browsers?).

It seems hacky, I'd like to know if there's a better way. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get the issue you show here. Why does it cause memory issues in browsers?

Comment: Hey @Duannx let's say there's a user ID that's huge like array[78000000] and its now instantiated without other items before it, the array initiates with null iterations preceeding it. I had memory related issues where I was having to use `Object.keys` to iterate over these arrays instead of their index. So it just seems like there should be a better way? If not that's also a good enough answer. I guess I'm just wondering if VueJS has a better method for this type of thing.

Comment: Oh. Finally, I got your question. I think akazarma's answer below is good for your situation

Comment: Whoops, where is the answer?